# why am i not able to import the class to another js file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, oop, node-modules

```
class hello{
    var1;
    var2;
    constructor(var1, var2){
        this.var1 = var1;
        this.var2 = var2;
    }

    getVar(){
        console.log(this.var1);
        console.log(this.var2);
    }
}
class h1 extends hello{
    var3 ;
    constructor(var1, var2,var3)
    {
        super(var1,var2);
        this.var3 = var3;
    }

    getAll(){
        console.log(this.var1);
        console.log(this.var2);
        console.log(this.var3);
    }
}

export {h1};
export {hello};
```

This is a module that I want to import from another file

This is the code of another file

```
import {h1,hello} from './temp'

let a = new h1("likith","ramu","asha");
a.getAll();
let b = new hello("raju","rahil");
b.getVar();
```

And this is the error that I'm getting for this code Please solve this problem

**
(node:14232) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
c:\Full stack dev Code\react.js\temp1.js:1
import {h1,hello} from './temp'
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1033:15)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1069:27)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.125 seconds

**

Comment: how are you running your code? if you're running it in backend or directly using node command then that is expected to happen as node.js by default doesn't use import syntax to import things

Comment: can you share the package.json file need more clarity ?

Comment: using node command bro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are trying to import a module it will be better if you try exporting your classes as a module as well, like this, `module.exports = { h1, hello };`
and then you can import it in your other file like this, `const { h1, hello } = require("./temp");`.
Hope this solves your problem

Comment: thx bro it worked and one more doubt how can i give an alias for that classes

Comment: what exactly do you want? can you elaborate a bit more? and you can mark this question as answered, as the above solution worked for you